# Opening files in new frame

Tags: find-file, conditionals

I'm using a fairly frame-oriented workflow (or trying to).  I've run into something strange.  If I write this:

```
(defun find-file-existing (filename)
    "Edit the existing file FILENAME.
Like \\[find-file], but only allow a file that exists, and do not allow
file names with wildcards."
    (interactive (nbutlast (find-file-read-args "Find existing file: " t)))
    (if (and (not (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
             (not (file-exists-p filename)))
        (error "%s does not exist" filename)
     (find-file-other-frame filename)
     (current-buffer)))
```

Then commands which use `find-file-existing` do what I want, including running the command directly from `SPC SPC`.

If I write this:

```
(defalias 'find-file 'find-file-other-frame)
```

Or this:

```
(defun find-file (filename)
    (interactive (nbutlast (find-file-read-args "Find file: " t)))
    (if (and (not (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
             nil)
        (error "%s does not exist" filename)
     (find-file-other-frame filename)
     (current-buffer)))
```

Then commands which use `find-file` (including running it from `SPC SPC`) do open the file in a new frame, but *also* change to that buffer in the current frame.

I've been over the code quite a bit and tried a few other variants, but the code paths seem almost the same to me (just changing if there is a file-existing check or not) and it's so strange that one does something different than the other.  Anyone have any ideas how this could be happening?  What should I be looking for?

Comment: You should *not*, in my opinion, intertwine `find-file` / `find-file-other-frame` with `defalias` as they are core functions used by a zillion built-in and third-party libraries.  If you want total control, I would suggest considering the usage of `find-file-noselect` and then target a specific frame if it exists, or create a new one if it does not ... use a custom `display-buffer` function ... See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18346785/2112489 for a working answer/example of how this might be done ....  Alternatively, look for other examples customizing the `display-buffer-alist`.

Comment: In the future, please indent your code conventionally. To do that, you might want to use `M-x untabify` before copying it in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, this:

```lisp
(if (and (not (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
         nil)
```

always evaluates the first `if` clause after that test, since the test always evaluates to `nil`.  That's not what you do in the first example.

(Indenting your code properly (conventionally) lets you see this kind of thing more easily.)

Comment: That's the intent, yes.  The if is only there in order to mirror the structure of the other code to make them as similar as possible.  The `defalias` version is of course my preferred, but I figured copying the exact code that works and making the smallest change possible was sane second attempt.